# Is it feasible to convert a QOpenGLWidget subclass into one that uses Metal instead of OpenGL?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, opengl, metal

Background:  I've got a Qt/C++ application that currently runs on (and is deployed on) MacOS/X, Windows, and Linux.  In one of the application's windows is a view of several dozen audio meters that needs to update frequently (i.e. at 20Hz or faster), so I implemented that view using a [QOpenGLWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html) and some simple OpenGL routines (see example code below).

This all works fine, however Apple has recently [deprecated OpenGL](https://www.anandtech.com/show/12894/apple-deprecates-opengl-across-all-oses) and wants all developers to convert their applications over to Apple's own "Metal" API instead; with the implication that eventually any program that uses OpenGL will stop working on MacOS/X.

I don't mind doing a little `#ifdef`-magic inside my code to support a separate API for MacOS/X, if I must, however it's not clear if coding to Metal is something that can actually be done in Qt currently.  If Metal-inside-Qt is possible, what is the proper approach to use?  If not, should I wait for a future release of Qt with better Metal support (e.g. [Qt 5.12](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/05/30/vulkan-for-qt-on-macos/)?) rather than waste my time trying to make Metal work in my current Qt version (5.11.2)?

```
// OpenGL meters view implementation (simplified for readability)
class GLMetersCanvas : public QOpenGLWidget
{  
public:
   GLMetersCanvas( [...] );

   virtual void initializeGL()
   {  
      glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
      glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
      glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
      glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
      glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
   }

   virtual void resizeGL(int w, int h)
   {  
      glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
      glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
      glLoadIdentity();
      glOrtho(0, w, 0, h, -1, 1);
      glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
      glLoadIdentity();
   }

   virtual void paintGL()
   {  
      const float meterWidth = [...];
      const float top        = [...];

      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      glBegin(GL_QUADS);

      float x = 0.0f;
      for (int i=0; i<numMeters; i++)
      {
         const float y = _meterHeight[i];

         glColor3f(_meterColorRed[i], _meterColorGreen[i], _meterColorBlue[i]);
         glVertex2f(x,            top);
         glVertex2f(x+meterWidth, top);
         glVertex2f(x+meterWidth, y);
         glVertex2f(x,            y);

         x += meterWidth;
      }
      glEnd();
   }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do what you want. It probably won't be a straightforward transition due to the fact that the code you posted uses very old deprecated features of OpenGL. Also, you might be better off just using CoreGraphics for the simple drawing you're doing. (It looks like a number of solid-colored, quads are being drawn. That's very easy and fairly efficient in CoreGraphics.) Metal seems like overkill for this job. That said, here are some ideas.

Metal is an inherently Objective-C API, so you will need to wrap the Metal code in some sort of wrapper. There are a number of ways you could write such a wrapper. You could make an Objective-C class that does your drawing and call it from your C++/Qt class. (You'll need to put your Qt class into a .mm file so the compiler treats it as Objective-C++ to call Objective-C code.) Or you could make your Qt class be an abstract class that has an implementation pointer to the class that does the real work. On Windows and Linux it could point to an object that does OpenGL drawing. On macOS it would point to your Objective-C++ class that uses Metal for drawing.

[This example of mixing OpenGL and Metal](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mixing_metal_and_opengl_rendering_in_a_view) might be informative for understanding how the 2 are similar and where they differ. Rather than having a context where you set state and make draw calls like in OpenGL, in Metal you create a command buffer with the drawing commands and then submit them to be drawn. Like with more modern OpenGL programming where you have vertex arrays and apply a vertex and fragment shader to every piece of geometry, in Metal you will also submit vertices and use a fragment and vertex shader for drawing.

To be honest, though, that sounds like a lot of work. (But it is certainly possible to do.) If you did it in CoreGraphics it would look something like this:

```
   virtual void paintCG()
   {  
      const float meterWidth = [...];
      const float top        = [...];

      CGRect backgroundRect = CGRectMake(...);
      CGContextClearRect(ctx, backgroundRect);

      float x = 0.0f;
      for (int i=0; i<numMeters; i++)
      {
         const float y = _meterHeight[i];

         CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, _meterColorRed[i], _meterColorGreen[i], _meterColorBlue[i]);
         CGRect meterRect = CGRectMake(x, y, meterWidth, _meterHeight[i]);
         CGContextFillRect(ctx, meterRect);

         x += meterWidth;
      }
      glEnd();
   }
```

It just requires that you have a `CGContextRef`, which I believe you can get from whatever window you're drawing into. If the window is an `NSWindow`, then you can call:

```
 NSGraphicsContext* nsContext = [window graphicsContext];
 CGContextRef ctx = nsContext.CGContext;
```

This seems easier to write and maintain than using Metal in this case.